# how to activate new instance in API Manager and stop old instance on mule?

Tags: api, mule4

I'm managing my API from exchange and it is working with Endpoint with Proxy. I gave implementation URL where i implemented the API in Cloudhub.

Now i did some change to raml file and published to Exchange with v2. Then i created instance same API in API manager.

[image]

Now the problem has come, I need to inactive the v1 and make active the v2.
How can i do this ?

Please suggest..,

Comment: This is not a Mule 4 question. It is about Anypoint API Manager.

Comment: Yes, it is mule api manager..,

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the Autodiscovery element apiName and version to point the new intance.

```
<api-platform-gw:api apiName="<API Name for V2>" version="<API Version for V2>" flowRef="api-main" create="false" apikitRef="api-config" doc:name="API Autodiscovery" />
```

hope this helps ...